# Resolving java.lang.Throwable exception in an android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am working on an android application which has a sqlite database. After writing the code in my app related to database operation, I am getting below exception. Though my application doesn't stop/crash, but I want to know how to resolve this exception. I am not sure why this exception is occurring, but I suppose it has to do with sqlite operations. I have closed all streams, connections and cursors as recommended. Below is the stack trace:

```
689-698/? E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
        at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
        at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:57)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
04-24 08:49:21.127      689-698/? E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
        at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
        at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:64)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
04-24 08:49:21.129      689-698/? E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
        at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
        at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:71)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

Could anyone please explain when does this exception occur and how to resolve it?

Comment: Can you please share source code?

Comment: are you using google maps api

Comment: @koutuk I am not using google maps API. I am simply reading from sqliteDB and writing to it.

Comment: @SujitDevkar are you trying to implement Backup in your app? Did you add a backupagent or set allowBackup=true in the manifest? I am getting the same error while adding a BackupAgent, but I can't make any sense of why it occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Like the log says:

> A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
>
> Explicit termination method 'close' not called

Note that the callstack shows where the resource was *created*. The message is printed when the resource is garbage-collected and it notices that it wasn't closed.

In your case, we can see that the resource is a `ParcelFileDescriptor`, and it was created automatically by the `IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact()` method (i.e., when your BackupAgent is getting a call through binder).

The log should disappear if you make sure to close the ParcelFileDescriptors passed to your BackupAgent subclass.

Comment: But manual closing of the ParcelFileDescriptors  is not done in Google example reference implementations for Android Backup.

Comment: I think you will find useful https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html