# Where is this ParcelFileDescriptor Leak Occurring?

Tags: android, android-backup-service, android-strictmode

I have implemented a [BackupAgent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/BackupAgent.html) following the guidelines for [Data Backup](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html).  The code behaves as expected until `StrictMode.VmPolicy` is set to detect leaked closeable objects.  After a backup is performed and GC occurs, CloseGuard reports a leaked `ParcelFileDescriptor` with this stack trace:

```
06-28 21:47:39.683  25072-25081/com.qbix.nub E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
            at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:179)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:905)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:897)
            at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:64)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-28 21:47:39.683  25072-25081/com.qbix.nub W/System.err﹕ StrictMode VmPolicy violation with POLICY_DEATH; shutting down.
06-28 21:47:39.683  25072-25081/com.qbix.nub I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 25072 SIG: 9
```

To confirm that I was not leaking the `ParcelFileDescriptor` in my `BackupAgent`, I stubbed `onBackup()` like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackup(ParcelFileDescriptor oldState, BackupDataOutput data, ParcelFileDescriptor newState) throws IOException {
    if (oldState != null) {
        oldState.close();
    }
    newState.close();
    return;
}
```

This change did not fix the leak.

These are the steps I use to reproduce the problem:

1. Modify app data to trigger a call to `BackupManager.dataChanged()`
2. Use `adb shell bmgr run` to force a backup operation
3. Initiate GC from `Android Studio`

I don't know enough about bound services to understand if the stack trace provides clues about whether the leak is in the system `BackupService` or is caused by an error in my code I am unable to see.  The continued occurrence of the leak when running with the stubbed `onBackup()` suggests to me that the leak is in the service.

While researching this issue, I found these other issues posted in the last few months that included the same leak report in their `logcats`:

[Resource leak in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31034193/resource-leak-in-android)

[Having problems With navigation Drawer in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954479/having-problems-with-navigation-drawer-in-android)

[Android - HTTP Get - Explicit Termination not called error. What am I missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488289/android-http-get-explicit-termination-not-called-error-what-am-i-missing)

[Resolving java.lang.Throwable exception in an android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861414/resolving-java-lang-throwable-exception-in-an-android)

The logcat shown above is from a KitKat device.  On another device running Lollipop, I think the same error is occurring.  The app is killed but the logcat does not include the CloseGuard dump. Don't know what I need to do to see that.

Comment: "The continued occurrence of the leak when running with the stubbed `onBackup()` suggests to me that the leak is in the service" -- I agree. OTOH, I didn't see an issue filed about it, and I would have expected one if every backup basically leaked a `ParcelFileDescriptor`. I detest the backup system on privacy and security grounds, so I have not used it personally.

Comment: I created [AOSP Issue 178506](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178506) for this.

Comment: @BobSnyder any news on this? I have the same issue on Android 5.1; I add a BackupAgent that does nothing and I get this leak. Could it have something to do with faulty manifest merging? Also in Google example backup app, they don't manually close the ParcelFileDescriptors.

Comment: @BobSnyder Btw, did you get backup working properly while getting this error?

Comment: @CommonsWare " I agree. OTOH, I didn't see an issue filed about it, and I would have expected one if every backup basically leaked a ParcelFileDescriptor" - but you have to enable StrictMode to see it, most people don't, right? Also bug might not be serious?